# CSS, container height is too small than expected, any fix?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am working on an educational page, I have faced a problem I can't really figure out how to solve. As you can see here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akazui/aYDwN/1/) the yellow box is much larger than the blue border on the left, I need that blue border to go all the way down with the yellow box (mail example), like the dotted orange border on the left. Is there any way to solve it with `CSS`, and `HTML`?

Comment: Please check your fiddle link.

Comment: And post your code here.

Comment: is the correct link: http://jsfiddle.net/aYDwN/

Comment: link updated, should work now

Comment: I think there is a more fundamental issue in the way you are structuring your HTML. Stuff like empty divs and unnecessary nesting are going to give you headaches in the end.

Comment: it looks like some of the empty divs are being used to do stuff like produce box shadows in IE. I suggest instead using a tool like [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/), which will allow you to use standard CSS for box shadows and other stuff, even in old IE versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's tons of errors in your code.

You must not give more than 1 element the same ID: `#col-2`.

You have given a div the class `.example`, and then you gave its child paragraphs the same class, so you gave each paragraph a height, so the parent took that height, that's why the border isn't stretching, because this element only has `32px height`.

So...

```
.example {
    /* background-image: url(../images/note_bg-line.jpg) repeat-y; */
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Then give the paragraphs another class which has `32px height`.

You specified the paragraphs like this...

```
<p class="p example"></p>
```

Remove this `p example` and just use this in CSS:

```
.example p {
        padding-top: 19px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    margin: -19px 0 0 0;
        height:32px;
}
```

You will get the **[desired effect...](http://jsfiddle.net/6pXvt/)**

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the height of the example-container class does the trick. As you want it to go all the way down like the orange border, `height: 295px;` works. 
http://jsfiddle.net/xbcBz/1/

```
.example-container {
    border-left: dotted 5px #2491F5;
    padding:5px;
    height: 295px;
}
```